# why the value of array_ops.expand_dims is below.The code comes from tensorflow contrib crf

Tags: python, tensorflow

why the result of offsets is below results. the code if from tensorflow crf.
tensorflow/contrib/crf/python/ops/crf.py.

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import math_ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops
batch_size,max_seq_len,num_tags=5,3,4
offsets = array_ops.expand_dims(math_ops.range(batch_size) * max_seq_len * num_tags, 1)
sess=tf.Session()
with sess:
    print(offsets.eval())
```

Comment: result is [[ 0]
 [12]
 [24]
 [36]
 [48]]

Answer (score 0):

oh ,i find that math_ops.range will get a list,then elements in the list will multiply (max_seq_len * num_tags),then the list will unsqueeze.

Answer (score 0):

With `math_ops.range(batch_size)` you create the tensor `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, similar as you would do with `range(batch_size)`. Then, you multiply this tensor by 3 * 4 = 12. Hence, the result is `[0, 12, 24, 36, 48]`. With `array_ops.expand_dims(...)`, you add another dimension to the tensor leading your result.